# undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass when passing User object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My application has user accounts and the users can log in to view the application. When a user is created by an admin a random password is generated and the user is prompted to change this if this is their first time logging in. Here is my SessionsController:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(user_name: params[:session][:user_name].to_s.downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      # Log the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
      if user.created_at == user.updated_at
        # If this is a first time user, then they need to change their password.
        log_in user



        # This user object is correct at this point, but after this point it is nil.
        redirect_to change_password_path(user)
      else
        log_in user
        redirect_to root_path # Redirects to the main page (parts page)
      end
    else
      # Create an error message.
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid User Name/Password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out
    redirect_to login_path
  end

end
```

Before being redirected to the change_password_path, the user object is not nil. Here are my routes for the redirect.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'sessions/new'

  resources :parts
  resources :users
  root "parts#index"

  get    '/change_password', to: 'users#first_time_password_change'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'

end
```

Once the user is redirected to change their password, the user object is nil and throws an error at _change_password.html.erb. Here is the error and the stack trace:

```
undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

app/views/users/_change_password.html.erb:2:in `block in _app_views_users__change_password_html_erb__3382781422752759150_70150174196820'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:39:in `block in capture'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:203:in `with_output_buffer'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:39:in `capture'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:758:in `form_with'
app/views/users/_change_password.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_users__change_password_html_erb__3382781422752759150_70150174196820'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `block in render'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:352:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:155:in `render'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:342:in `block in render_partial'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41:in `instrument'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:331:in `render_partial'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `render'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:35:in `render'
app/views/users/first_time_password_change.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_users_first_time_password_change_html_erb___4022541670546187761_70150174275000'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `block in render'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:352:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:155:in `render'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41:in `instrument'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:51:in `block in render_template'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:59:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:50:in `render_template'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:141:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:24:in `render'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:29:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:33:in `default_render'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `block in send_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `tap'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
request_store (1.4.0) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.11.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.11.0) lib/puma/server.rb:624:in `handle_request'
puma (3.11.0) lib/puma/server.rb:438:in `process_client'
puma (3.11.0) lib/puma/server.rb:302:in `block in run'
puma (3.11.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Here are the first_time_password_change.html.erb

```
<%= render 'change_password', user: @user %>
<%= logger.info "FUDGE " + @user.class.to_s %>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <%= link_to 'Show', @user %> |
        <%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the _change_password.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: user, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2 style="color: red;"><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li style="color: red;"><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h1>Change Password</h1>
    <div class="control-group">
      <%= form.label :first_name, class: "control-label" %>
      <label style="font-size: 20px; font-weight:normal;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= @user.first_name %></label>
    </div><br />

    <div class="control-group">
      <%= form.label :last_name, class: "control-label" %>
      <label style="font-size: 20px; font-weight:normal;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= @user.last_name %></label>
    </div><br />

    <div class="control-group">
      <%= form.label :user_name, class: "control-label" %>
      <label style="font-size: 20px; font-weight:normal;">&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= @user.user_name %></label>
    </div><br />

    <div class="control-group">
      <%= form.label :email, class: "control-label" %>
      <label style="font-size: 20px; font-weight:normal;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= @user.email %></label>
    </div><br />

    <div class="control-group">
      <%= form.label :privledges, class: "control-label"%>
      <label style="font-size: 20px; font-weight:normal;">&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= @user.privledges %></label>
    </div><br />

    <div class="control-group">
      <%= form.label :new_password, class: "control-label" %>
      <%= form.text_field :password, id: :password, class: 'form-control', value: "" %>
    </div><br />

    <div class="control-group">
      <%= form.label :confirm_password, class: "control-label" %>
      <%= form.text_field :confirm_password, id: :confirm_password, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div><br />

    <div class="actions">
      <%= form.submit 'Change Password', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
    <br />

  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And Here is the UserController

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'random_password_generator'

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # Check that the person accessing the application is logged in:
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # GET /changepassword
  def first_time_password_change
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.password = RandomPasswordGenerator.generate(10, :skip_symbols => true).to_s
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save 
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    password_is_valid = password_update_is_valid(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      if password_is_valid
        if @user.update(user_params)
          format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end 
      else
        format.html { render :edit, notice: '' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private 
  def password_update_is_valid(user)
    is_valid = true
    user_pass = params[:user][:password]
    user_conf = params[:user][:confirm_password]
    # Check if the parameters were passed as nil objects
    if user_pass.nil? or user_conf.nil?
      is_valid = false
      user.errors[:base] << "Please fill both the Password and Confirm Password fields."
    else
      # Check if the password and confirmation passwords are empty
      if user_pass == "" or user_conf == ""
        user.errors[:base] << "Please fill both the Password and Confirm Password fields."
        is_valid = false
      end
      # Check if the password length is less than 5 characters long
      if user_pass.length < 5
        user.errors[:base] << "Password must be at least 5 characters long."
        is_valid = false
      end
      # Check if the password and confirm password fields match.
      if user_pass != user_conf
        user.errors[:base] << "Password and Confirm Password must match."
        is_valid = false
      end
    end
    return is_valid
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :user_name, :email, :password, :privledges, :password_digest)
    end

end
```

I am a bit new to rails but the console has some strange output. The first_time_change_password.html.erb is being rendered, followed by the _change_password.html.erb, which is as expected. What is weird is that the first_time_change_password.html.erb is rendered again and the error occurs.

```
tarted GET "/change_password.21" for 107.213.96.34 at 2018-01-11 15:48:10 +0000
Cannot render console from 107.213.96.34! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by UsersController#first_time_password_change as 
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 21], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering users/first_time_password_change.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/_change_password.html.erb (4.6ms)
  Rendered users/first_time_password_change.html.erb within layouts/application (8.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 17ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <%= form_with(model: user, local: true) do |form| %>
    2:   <% if user.errors.any? %>
    3:     <div id="error_explanation">
    4:       <h2 style="color: red;"><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
    5:       <ul>

app/views/users/_change_password.html.erb:2:in `block in _app_views_users__change_password_html_erb__3382781422752759150_70150174196820'
app/views/users/_change_password.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_users__change_password_html_erb__3382781422752759150_70150174196820'
app/views/users/first_time_password_change.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_users_first_time_password_change_html_erb___4022541670546187761_70150174275000'
```

I am a bit new to rails and I am studying web development so please have mercy on me.

Also, I am running Rails 5.1.4 on Cloud 9.

Thank you to everyone who is willing to take the time to look at this and I am sorry about all of the code.

Comment: Try changing `<%= render 'change_password', user: @user %>` to `<%= render 'change_password', user: current_user %>`

Comment: Wow, I did this then changed all of the @user instances in the form to current_user. This worked!!!! But since I am learning and Ruby on Rails seems like a marketable skill, can you explain why this works?

Answer (score 0):

In the `UsersController` in the before action 
`before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`
add the `first_time_password_change` method.
`before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :first_time_password_change]`
As `@user` is not set in that method user is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for an explanation, you were seeing `undefined method 'errors' for nil:NilClass` because `user` object is actually `nil` there. All starts when you call `<%= render 'change_password', user: @user %>` without setting `@user` in your action `first_time_password_change`. Devise makes a helper `current_user` available if a user is logged in. Since you make the action available only to `authenticated` users with  `before_action :authenticate_user!`, it's recommended to use `current_user` rather than setting up another instance `@user`. And you can make use of `current_user` in the partial directly without passing it in locals. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not a server-side validation this called client-side validation, this matching user data not creating data with validation

**Login**

Allow a user to sign in with her/his valid email/username and password. The authentication process happens by matching the email/username and password in the database, allowing the user access to the protected actions only if the given information matches the recorded values successfully. If not, the user will be redirected to the login page again.

This is not creating data to the database with model validation this is matching data with a database which already exist after that create a session to hold id.

That's why you need to remove this client-side error code only for login form, after removing this code

```
<% if user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2 style="color: red;"><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
        <ul>
            <% user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li style="color: red;"><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Add flash section which holds your login error like below

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <section class="<%="#{name}" %>-message-section"> 
        <div class="container"> 
            <div class="row"> 
                <div class="col-md-12"> 
                    <div class="alert-message <%="#{name}" %>-message">
                        <p><%= msg if msg.is_a?(String) %></p>
                        <i class="icofont icofont-close"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
<% end %>
```

Hope to help